# Call to AfxOleTerm in a MFC application prior to using a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, ole

In a MFC application, the `AfxOleInit()` method is called in the application `InitInstance()` method.
I need to call this method because I am using OLE objects in the application.

I am also using a DLL which doesn't work well if `AfxOleInit()` has been called.

I was thinking about:

- calling the **AfxOleTerm()** prior to loading the DLL,
- doing what I have to do with the DLL,
- calling `AfxOleInit()` afterwards (in the main program, not in the DLL).

Is it an acceptable solution?

Note that in practice, if I do this, the DLL actually behaves properly.

Answer (score 0):

Calling AfxOleTerm Prior to the DLL calls is no good idea. The reason is simple: Doing this may cause all currently created COM objects for this thread to get destroyed, or they nay not be accessible any longer.

Anyway calling AfxOleInit inside a DLL is no good idea. The problem is, that this call is always specific to a thread.

Only the application should call AfxOleInit in its thread and than it should perform any further action.

And to make it more complicated, it also depends on what model of MFC you are using. Sharing the MFC in a DLL would cause AfxOleInit to act different than using a statically linked DLL.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be better to call AfxOleInit() prior to using OLE objects and AfxOleTerm() after they have done their job?

Comment: Precision: the main program uses the MFC in a static library.

Comment: AfxOLeTerm doesn't need to be called. If AfxOleInit is used AfxOleTerm is called automatically for the thread. If Th emain Programm uses COM or one of it's DLLs that is called from within the context of the EXE the thread should be prepared with a clal to AfxOleInit.

Comment: Please, your second sentence is full of typos, can you correct them because I don't understand what you're explaining.

Comment: AfxOleTerm doesn't need to be called. If AfxOleInit is used AfxOleTerm is called automatically for the thread. If the main program uses COM or one of it's DLLs that is called from within the context of the EXE the thread should be prepared with a call to AfxOleInit.